# The model item passed into the is of type 'LoginModel', but this instance requires a model item of type 'HomeViewModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The full text of the error I am getting

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FashionNova.Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FashionNova.Web.ViewModels.HomeViewModel'.

This is my HomeController

```
namespace FashionNova.Web.Controllers
{
    using FashionNova.Services;
    using FashionNova.Web.ViewModels;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IMainCategoryService mainCategoryService;

        public HomeController(IMainCategoryService mainCategoryService)
        {
            this.mainCategoryService = mainCategoryService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
        {
            var categoriesViewModel = this.mainCategoryService
                .GetAllMainCategories<HomeMainCategoryViewModel>();

            model.AllCategoriesViewModel = categoriesViewModel;

            return this.View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error() => this.View();
    }
}
```

This is my layout

```
@using FashionNova.Data.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fashion Nova is the top online fashion store for women & men. Shop sexy club dresses, jeans, shoes, bodysuits, skirts & more. Cheap & affordable fashion online">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icons/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Plugins CSS File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Main CSS File -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <header class="header">
        <partial name="Partials/_HeaderTopPartial"/>
        <div class="header-middle sticky-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-left">
                    <ul class="menu sf-arrows">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <partial name="Partials/NavigationPartials/_NavigationHeaderLeftCategoryPartial"/>
                        <partial name="Partials/NavigationPartials/_NavigationHeaderLeftProductsPartial"/>
                        <partial name="Partials/NavigationPartials/_NavigationHeaderLeftPagesPartial"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <partial name="Partials/NavigationPartials/_NavigationHeaderCenterPartial"/>
                <div class="header-right">
                    <partial name="Partials/NavigationPartials/_NavigationHeaderRightPartial"/>
                </div><!-- End .header-right -->
            </div><!-- End .container -->
        </div><!-- End .header-middle -->
    </header><!-- End .header -->

    <main class="main">
        @this.RenderBody()
    </main>
    <partial name="Partials/_FooterPartial"/>
</div>

<div class="mobile-menu-overlay"></div>
<div class="mobile-menu-container">
    <partial name="Partials/_MobileMenuPartial"/>
</div>

<a id="scroll-top" href="#top" title="Top" role="button">
    <i class="icon-angle-up"></i>
</a>

<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/main.min.js"></script>
@this.RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works normal, until I try to pass a model to ANY of the partials in the layout, be it footer partial, header partial, navigation partial.

I am passing the HomeViewModel, to the Category part of the Navigation partial, so I don't mess with the other parts of the navigation

```
@model HomeViewModel
<li>
    <a href="category.html" class="sf-with-ul">Categories</a>
    <div class="megamenu megamenu-fixed-width">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="menu-title">
                            <a href="#">Variations 1<span class="tip tip-new">New!</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-banner-full-width.html">Fullwidth Banner<span class="tip tip-hot">Hot!</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-banner-boxed-slider.html">Boxed Slider Banner</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-banner-boxed-image.html">Boxed Image Banner</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-sidebar-left.html">Left Sidebar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-sidebar-right.html">Right Sidebar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-flex-grid.html">Product Flex Grid</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-horizontal-filter1.html">Horizontal Filter1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-horizontal-filter2.html">Horizontal Filter2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- End .col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="menu-title">
                            <a href="#">Variations 2</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Product List Item Types</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-infinite-scroll.html">Ajax Infinite Scroll</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-3col.html">3 Columns Products</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-4col.html">4 Columns Products <span class="tip tip-new">New</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-5col.html">5 Columns Products</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-6col.html">6 Columns Products</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-7col.html">7 Columns Products</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="category-8col.html">8 Columns Products</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- End .col-lg-6 -->
                </div><!-- End .row -->
            </div><!-- End .col-lg-8 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="banner">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="~/images/menu-banner-2.jpg" alt="Menu banner">
                    </a>
                </div><!-- End .banner -->
            </div><!-- End .col-lg-4 -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- End .megamenu -->
</li>
```

My loginPartial is contained in another part of the navigation partial, I tried to divide them so the wrong model doesnt get passed, but even after that - the same issue comes back.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Pages</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Checkout</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="checkout-shipping.html">Checkout Shipping</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="checkout-shipping-2.html">Checkout Shipping 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="checkout-review.html">Checkout Review</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="my-account.html">My Account</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="single.html">Blog Post</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <partial name="_LoginPartial"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am passing the HomeViewModel to Index, cause I want to load all the categories, products and 2 rows of products in the front page, but when I do it - the login gets broken.

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal repro of your issue.  If that doesn't help you identify the problem yourself, it will help you get some suggestions.  Three walls of code/text is going to cause most of us to just go on to the next question that is more easily understood.

Comment: Where's your `this.View()`?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan, which this.View() you speaking about? The Index one?

Comment: In your main view,you pass LoginModel,and it seems that you use razor pages?And in your partial view,you pass  HomeViewModel.The main view and partial view should pass the same model.I suggest that you need to provide the main view and the partial view that could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partial view is expecting a model of type `HomeViewModel` but you did not specify it when referencing the partial view from your _Layout.cshtml, hence the page by default sends the Parent Model to your partial view which causes the error you are having.

You need to pass the expected model like below：

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_myPartial",new HomeViewModel())
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to pass data to partial view in _Layout.cshtml,here is a smiple demo like below:

1._Layout.cshtml:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_myPartial",new HomeViewModel() { Id=1,Name="aa"})
```

2._myPartial.cshtml:

```
@model HomeViewModel
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But how I can provide the information to the HomeViewModel, if its a new?

Isn't it best to leave all the logic into the controller and just pass the model?

Comment: I ended up in making the navigation partial as a component, but your logic and directions helped me to find this solution.

Thank you!