# .net Core MVC Partial view not rendering when calling a different index page in my project

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi Please assist Im facing a weird issue here...

My partial view loads correctly when I start up my project its placed under shared views in _Layout under "_RegisterPartial" inside this partial view I have two other Partial views "_Login" and "_Register" (use them in a pop up modal)they seem to load fine when I am on the home index page. The issue then starts when I access a different index page from a different controller and then the project will complain about about a different model being expected on the partial views. please assist

```
                                <button class="btn header-btn-collapse-nav" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".header-nav-main nav">
                                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Inside that partial view

```
    <div class="header-nav-features header-nav-features-no-border header-nav-features-lg-show-border order-1 order-lg-2">
        <div class="header-nav-feature header-nav-features-user d-inline-flex mx-2 pr-2 signin" id="headerAccount">
            <a href="#" class="header-nav-features-toggle">
                <i class="far fa-user"></i> Sign In
            </a>
            <div class="header-nav-features-dropdown header-nav-features-dropdown-mobile-fixed header-nav-features-dropdown-force-right" id="headerTopUserDropdown">
                <partial name="_Login" />

                <partial name="_RegisterPartial" />
```

my login partial

```
@model FSTC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel

For my register partial view head I use
@model FSTC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti93W.png)

Error Im receiving

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FSTC.ViewModel.DetailsView', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FSTC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.
```

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FSTC.ViewModel.DetailsView', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FSTC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

Your partial view is expecting a model of type `LoginModel` but you did not specify it when referencing the partial view from your Parent View, hence the page by default sends the Parent Model to your partial view which causes the error you are having.

Please check which partial view needs a model of type 'LoginModel' and check which parent view needs a model of type 'DetailsView'.Change like below:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_YourPartial",new LoginModel())
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58587431/11398810